Not able to create lakehouse in Microsoft Fabric using api and spn
Using a SPN I am able to create workspace in MS Fabric and retrieve other data but not able to create lakehouse or list lakehouses. Getting the below error.
{
"requestId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
"errorCode": "PrincipalTypeNotSupported",
"message": "The operation is not supported for the principal type"
}
Is it supported?

No it's no supported using an SPN, as the error message indicates

Many of the APIs are not yet supported for Service Principals.  This is coming.  In the mean time you'll have to use a user principal (like your own identity).
